# Gulp installation errors on terminal

Tags: npm, installation, gulp

When I install `gulp` using `npm install gulp-cli -g`

It shows me an error in the picture below. Can someone help me?

I have tried to change administrator access and delete `node_modules` in my hard drive, but it still shows me errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you install packages **globally**, by **default**, `npm` will install them in **`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`** which requires
 **`root` permissions**.

There are **3 solutions** to your problem:

#### Install the package as root user

```
sudo npm install -g gulp-cli
```

---

#### Change the owner of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

---

#### Recommended: [Manually change npm’s default directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory)

> In your home directory, create a directory for global installations:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.npm-global
> ```
>
> Configure npm to use the new directory path:
>
> ```
> npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
> ```
>
> In your preferred text editor, open or create a `~/.profile` file and
>   add this line:
>
> ```
> export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> On the command line, update your system variables:
>
> ```
> source ~/.profile
> ```
>
> To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:
>
> ```
> npm install -g gulp-cli
> ```